# How to translate it into a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

guys.
I have this cenario:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="1">First Option</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option</option>
            <option value="3">Tirdth Option</option>
        </select>
        Name of Process 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="1">First Option</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option</option>
            <option value="3">Tirdth Option</option>
        </select>
        Name of Process 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option value="1">First Option</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option</option>
            <option value="3">Tirdth Option</option>
        </select>
        Name of Process 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

The number of options in select block and the processes are both retrivied from a database. How can I translate it into a ViewModel property? Something like a List of Processes and a List of Options? But I want to have it into one single property. Can you help me with this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper object which holds the name and an array of the options. So the class would look like:

```
public class WrapperObject
{
   public String Name { get;set;}
   public List<Options> {get;set;}
}

public class Options
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public String DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

The viewmodel would be a list of the WrapperObjects and you could loop them.

Comment: +1 I guess that's as much love as you'll get :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Keethanjan. That part I did already. My doubt is: with this ViewModel done, how can I use the HtmlHelpers to make the View? My code is not working for it.